# ARIA validation error: Bad value slider for attribute role

Tags: html, accessibility, validation, wai-aria

I am trying to validate against W3C validator a page that contains:

```
<button role="slider"></button>
```

And the validator tells me:

> Bad value slider for attribute role on element button

Any idea why? I can't find any explanation in the ARIA specs.
I have seen [in this blog post](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2009/01/how-can-i-validate-xhtml-aria/) that `landmark` roles are not supported by the validator, but slider is a `widget` role. Also, [another post in the same blog](http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2008/05/aria-slider-part-1/) uses the code above as an example...

Simply feeding the code above to the validator allows to reproduce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `button` element has *Implicit ARIA Semantics*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#sec-implicit-aria-semantics) in HTML5.  The role must be either `button`, `link`, `menuitem`, `menuitemcheckbox`, `menuitemradio` or `radio`.

Comment: Thanks! I have a page with the same problem that I validated some time ago (about 1 month), but the error was not raised. Do you know if this was handled by the validator only recently?

Comment: Was the page you validated a month ago HTML5 or XHTML1?

Comment: Not sure if there have been any recent updates, but the restrictions above only apply to HTML5 documents AFAIK.